# How to sign and encrypt mail using openssl?

Tags: email, openssl

I am trying to send and encrypt mail using openssl.

So far, I figure I should use theese commands:

```
cat ${content} | \
    openssl smime -encrypt -inkey lib/me.crt  -aes256 -subject "$titre (cs)" -to someone@hotmail.com lib/MAQUETTE1-me.pem | \
    openssl smime -sign -inkey lib/myroot.key -signer lib/MAQUETTE1-myroot.pem -passin pass:myroot1 | \
    tee ~/tmp7/$T/mail-cs-$c |\
    sendmail -t someone@hotmail.com
```

another way without `cat` and `tee`

```
openssl smime -encrypt -in ${contents} -out tmp1 -inkey lib/me.crt  -aes256 -subject "$titre (cs)" -to someone@hotmail.com lib/MAQUETTE1-me.pem 
openssl smime -sign -in tmp2 -out tmp2 -inkey lib/myroot.key -signer lib/MAQUETTE1-myroot.pem -passin pass:myroot1 

sendmail -t someone@hotmail.com < tmp2
```

same result.

This work fine, except that I loose the first few line of `${content}`, which is annoying for plain text content, and fatal when sending binary file.

Have I missed something ?

first lines of `~/tmp7/$T/mail-cs-$c` (before being sent to sendmail)

```
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha1"; boun
    dary="----396B3702CFDE34F2D44DF5C360D9F6FD"

    This is an S/MIME signed message

    ------396B3702CFDE34F2D44DF5C360D9F6FD
    To: someone@hotmail.com
    Subject: contenu du tex 17 (cs)
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
    Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    MII5sgYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoII5ozCCOZ8CAQAxgfcwgfQCAQAwXTBQMQswCQYDVQQG
    EwJGUjEPMA0GA1UECAwGRnJhbmNlMQ0wCwYDVQQHDARMeW9uMQ0wCwYDVQQKDARP
```

EDIT:

- I want to use command line, I already use thunderbird with proper plugin, and it works fine.
- `cat` and `tee` are standard unix command,  use very often, I don't believe they can p be part of the problem.
- I edited body to remove cat and tee.

Comment: Why not use Thunderbird with the Enigmail plugin?

Comment: @raz I know how to do it with GUI tool, I just want to do it by shell/command line.

Comment: I think the encryption is fine.  The main question is what is causing the first few lines to be removed.  Is it the `cat` or `tee`?

Comment: Why not leaving `cat` out and just using `openssl smime -encript .... < ${content}` ?

Comment: Do you have MIME (entity) headers, terminated by an empty line, in the $contents file? If not, either add them -- if you can't or don't want to change the file, you can do something like `(echo Content-type: text/plain; echo; cat $contents) | openssl smime ...` -- or add option `-text` which does that for you. For a 'binary file' the receiving MUA probably needs you to be specific, like `image/png` or whatever it is. Aside: `smime -encrypt` doesn't need or use `-inkey` (the only key it uses is the publickey in the recipient cert, which is a positional argument).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Great ! that setlle it ! I change `cat ..`  by `(file --mime-type ${content} | awk '{printf "Content-type: %s\n",$2} ' ; echo ; cat ${content} )` and it work. thanks.

Comment: @RoraΖ : Enigmail no longer works with recent versions of Thunderbird for nearly a year, and Thunderbird doesn’t let you to select the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by dave_thompson_085,

I change

```
 cat ${content} |\
```

by

```
 $(file --mime-type ${content} | awk '{printf "Content-type: %s\n",$2} ' ; echo ; cat ${content} ) |\
```

and it work fine, I juste have to figure out how to send binary document, but that shouldn't be a problem.

thanks every one for help.